# Separate codebase for responsive website and mobile apps?

Tags: mobile, angularjs, bootstrap, responsive-design

I made a simple responsive single page web app (about 5 views) to replace our old jsf web application using angularjs+bootstrap. Now looking into frameworks like ionic, cordova and trigger.io.

what I don't understand is, am I supposed to directly reuse my responsive web app code in, say, ionic framework? I know there are differences between those frameworks but the main idea is, write app using js+html5 and embed it ino a webview to run in different platforms.

How much and what can I reuse from my angular+bootstrap web app? I suppose I can reuse angularjs services that talk to backend, but not controllers or ui. Or mobile app and responsive website are totally different codebases with different aims/approaches?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a simple web application, you can completely share the codebases between the website and the mobile application. In this case, you basically just wrap your website code in the mobile application (Cordova does follow this way of thought).

It makes sense to diverge the codebases in some cases, but I think that this is the exception to the rule, not the norm.

Comment: So, the mobile app will look and function just like the mobile website, but just wrapped in an app? With the same theme, same html etc?

Comment: In this case yes. If this is not the intention, you can use a different theme, and choose the right one in build time. So there is still *one codebase*, but *multiple targets*.